# reverse the order of both columns and rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
                 Bottom 25%  Lower 25%  Upper 25%   Top 25%
Bottom 25%       0.119318   0.073864   0.073864  0.073864
Lower 25%        0.039773   0.051136   0.045455  0.022727
Upper 25%        0.051136   0.068182   0.090909  0.034091
Top 25%          0.034091   0.034091   0.062500  0.125000
```

In the pandas dataframe above, what is the best way to reverse the order of both columns and rows? E.g. columns should be `Top 25%  Upper 25%  Lower 25%  Bottom 25%` instead of `Bottom 25%  Lower 25%  Upper 25%   Top 25%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.iloc` with a negative step.

```
df.iloc[::-1,::-1]
```

Output:

```
             Top 25%  Upper 25%  Lower 25%  Bottom 25%
Top 25%     0.125000   0.062500   0.034091    0.034091
Upper 25%   0.034091   0.090909   0.068182    0.051136
Lower 25%   0.022727   0.045455   0.051136    0.039773
Bottom 25%  0.073864   0.073864   0.073864    0.119318
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reindex. df.columns[::-1] reverses the order of columns.

This will work even if your rows are not ordered the same as columns.

```
df.reindex(index=df.columns[::-1],columns=df.columns[::-1])
Out[4]: 
             Top 25%  Upper 25%  Lower 25%  Bottom 25%
 Top 25%         NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
Upper 25%   0.034091   0.090909   0.068182    0.051136
Lower 25%   0.022727   0.045455   0.051136    0.039773
Bottom 25%  0.073864   0.073864   0.073864    0.119318
```